# reading Google calendar values

Tags: events, groovy, google-calendar-api, missingmethodexception

I have set an event successfully using

```
myEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("TEST"))
myEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("See how much text will fit in there"))
```

Then I have successfully read the event record.

This works

```
myTitle = ret.getTitle().getPlainText()
```

But this throws an error

```
myTitle = ret.getContent().getPlainText()

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
com.google.gdata.data.TextContent.getPlainText()
```

No better if I make it

```
myTitle = req.getContent().toString()
```

Any ideas what I have missed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
myContent = ret.getTextContent()
```

or:

```
myContent = ret.getPlainTextContent()
```

Comment: It does.. If you do ret.getContent().getType() it returns 1 indicating it is text

Comment: It is the getPlainText() that throws that exception

Comment: Fixed.. Thanks  Just needs myContent = ret.getPlainTextContent()